# How to pack before_filter in some_module.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Module.rb file with code

```
    module Finder
      module InstanceMethods
        def my_func
          @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.send :include, InstanceMethods
        base.before_filter :my_func
      end
    end
```

And Controller with code

```
include Finder
```

But my app crashes with code

```
    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    Extracted source (around line #5):

    2: 
    3: <p>
    4:   <b>Name:</b>
    5:   <%= @post.name %>
    6: </p>
    7: 
    8: <p>
```

It seems like @post didn't working. Whats wrong?

Comment: I think before_filter is class level, not instance

Comment: That should work fine. Are you sure you're getting the right `Finder`? Have you checked the `my_func` is getting called and that `params[:id]` is what you think it is?

Comment: @muistooshort the funniest thing is that my app is crashes even if I don't make any changes to Controller file and add "include Finder" that is empty module.

Comment: It would crash because nobody would be setting `@post`. Toss a quick logger call in `my_func` to see if it is being called and if it is setting a sensible `@post` value.

Comment: @muistooshort , thank you for your help. I did my task. My module didn't work 'cause I didn't load lib path in application.rb. I will answer on my question tomorrow, where I'll type the right and working variant :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. 
My module didn't work 'cause I didn't add line

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

into application.rb file.After that, I made my task working with this code:

```
module Finder
  def self.included(base)
     base.class_eval do
       before_filter :my_func, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     end
  end
  def my_func
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```